# How can I fix a blurry icon in the Unity dash?

Tags: firefox, unity-dash

In my particular case the Firefox icon in my Unity dash is blurry and of low resolution.

How can I fix this or identify the source of the problem?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Firefox blurry icon]

**Installed version:**

```
ii  firefox                                              49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Comment: Hello Robert. Had an issue like this myself. Any case you are using Thunderbird? If so check if there is a 22x22 icon `firefox.png` under `${HOME}/.thunderbird` directory and try to safely delete it (move it temporally to another directory). You can use Gnome Tweak Tool to change a theme in order for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKarnezis! Indeed, I use Thunderbird but I don't have an image in this folder. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/eUQlCUX.png) screenshot.

Comment: Can you try `find | grep "firefox.png"` inside this directory to recursively search inside it?

Comment: I found them and renamed them! `orschiro@x230:~/.thunderbird$ find | grep "firefox.png"./2yc49soc.default/extensions/{9533f794-00b4-4354-aa15-c2bbda6989f8}/chrome/skin/icons/linux/hicolor/22x22/apps/firefox.png`

Comment: @AlexKarnezis and this solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nothing at all :) I posted the above as an answer, in case someone else meets the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Thunderbird, there is a chance that it has inserted a low resolution `firefox.png` file in your `${HOME}/.thunderbird` directory, that is used by Dash. To search if this is the case, open a terminal and run:

```
cd ${HOME}/.thunderbird
find | grep "firefox.png"
```

If you find the file, delete it and restart Firefox.